# Is this the right approach to solving this proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation

The original statement is: If for all $a,b,c$ are integers and $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ then at least $1$ of $a,b,c$ is even.

$P$ is "for all $a,b,c$ are integers".
$Q$ is "$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$".
$R$ is "at least $1$ of $a,b,c$ is even".

I see this as $P$ and $Q$ implies $R$.

Negating this would be $P$ and $Q$ and not $R$. So suppose: For all $a,b,c$ are integers and $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ and $a,b,c$ are odd.

Taking the contrapositive would be not $R$ implies not $P$ or not $Q$. So suppose: if $a,b,c$ are odd then there exists an integer $a,b,c$ or $a^2 + b^2\ne c^2$.

I feel like the negation looks alright. However, for the contrapositive, logically it looks like it makes sense, but doesn't look right. Any feedback on my thought processes would be helpful.

Comment: The contrapositive is "if $a,b,c$ are all odd integers then $a^2+b^2\neq c^2$."

Comment: Why don't you try contradiction...it's less complicated than contrapositive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For contrapositive, as @lulu commented the statement should be **if $a,b,c$ are all odd then $a^2+b^2\neq c^2$** Now let's prove this

Assume all are odd, and let $a=2i+1,b=2j+1,c=2k+1$ where $i,j,k>0 \:\:\textrm{and}\:\:\in\mathbb{I}$

$$(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2=(2k+1)^2$$
$$\implies i^2+i+j^2+j-k^2-k=\frac{-1}{4}$$ But L.H.S is always an integer but $-1/4$ is not an integer...so a contradiction occurs that is, we proved the contrapositive statement

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque okk...but how do you check whether a question is a dupe or not...approach zero or something else???

Comment: See e.g. [this meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/242) and its links.